# Coq proof tactics

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am a beginner at Coq proof system (about 4 days). I've tried hard, but I am not able to prove the following.

```
forall a b c : nat, S (S (a + b)) = S (S (a + c)) -> b = c.
```

As far as I know, we need to prove the bijectivity of +, so that we can somehow use `f(b) = f(c) -> b = c`. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in Vinz's answer, you can find the bijectivity theorem about `plus` directly in the Coq standard library. You can also prove it directly using primitive tactics and mathematical induction on `a` as follows.

```
Theorem plus_l_bij: forall a b c : nat, a + b = a + c -> b = c.
Proof.
induction a as [|a'].
  intros b c H. apply H.
  intros b c H. simpl plus in H. inversion H. apply IHa' in H1. apply H1.
Qed.
```

After `induction a`, the base case `a = 0` is trivial.

The proof for the second case `a = S a'`, rearranges

```
S a' + b = S a' + c
```

to

```
S (a' + b) = S (a' + c)
```

and then removes the constructor `S` using its bijectivity. Finally, the induction hypothesis can be applied to finish the proof.

Answer (score 3):

Using `SearchAbout plus` or `SearchPattern (_ + _ = _ + _ -> _)` you could check the available lemmas about `+`. But if you didn't import the correct modules, that could be useless. What I usually do is that I go look at the online documentation. [Here is the documentation for plus](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Arith.Plus.html) and you could have a particular look to `plus_reg_l` and `plus_reg_r`.